# Basic error in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this: `problem(a(1,2,3),P)`
And I need to get this: `P = [e(1, 3), e(2, 0)]`

I just started with Prolog a few days ago and I wrote this:

```
problem([a(X,Y,Z)],P) :- P is [e(X,Z),e(Y,0)].
```

But I only get a `false` by answer. What error did I make?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `is/2` predicate is used for evaluating arithmetic expressions. In your case, a simple fact would suffice:

```
problem(a(X,Y,Z), [e(X,Z),e(Y,0)]).
```

For example:

```
?- [user].
problem(a(X,Y,Z), [e(X,Z),e(Y,0)]).
|: ^D

?- problem(a(1,2,3), P).
P = [e(1, 3), e(2, 0)].
```